# How to stop multithread start by for loop condition

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, for-loop

This code will show you how I started multiple threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    doImages    = new DoImages(this, TCPPORT + i);
    var thread  = new Thread(doImages.ThreadProc);
    thread.Name = "Imaging";
    var param = (i + 1).ToString();                      
    thread.Start(param);
}
```

Now I'm trying to stop the threads before closing my application but I don't know how to do that?

Comment: You'll need to keep an object that tracks the threads inside your class. Implement a Dispose method for your class that kills the tracked threads and you should be ok.

Comment: 'Now I'm trying to stop the threads before closing my application but I don't know how to do that?' - have you tried not stopping them?  What really bad thing happens if you don't stop them, don't call Thread.Join(), don't signal them to stop, don't do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple option is to store references to all of the threads that you spawn and then join all of them when you are done:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    doImages    = new DoImages(this, TCPPORT + i);
    var thread  = new Thread(doImages.ThreadProc);
    threads[i] = thread;
    thread.Name = "Imaging";
    var param = (i + 1).ToString();                    
    thread.Start(param);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    threads[i].Join();
}
```

This will wait for all of the threads to finish before the application terminates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not all of your code success but I using your thread array ideal to stop my threads by loop over each of thread items. and I create array of DoImages class to STOP it too.

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest and most reliable way is to make them Background threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    doImages    = new DoImages(this, TCPPORT + i);
    var thread  = new Thread(doImages.ThreadProc);
    thread.Name = "Imaging";
    var param = (i + 1).ToString();  
    thread.IsBackground = true;          // **
    thread.Start(param);
}
```

Background threads are automatically terminated when the Process (main thread) is exiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `thread.Abort();` if you keep references to your thread objects and simply want to exit your app.

My guess would be that you would like to finish execution and then close app. For this you would need to synchronize your threads using `Join()` or other synch method.

Comment: But Thread.Abort() should usually be avoided. Since this is about exiting the process anyway it can be used.